# Excerpt function for any content

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, excerpt

Is there an excerpt output function in wordpress I can hook into regardless of the field used, rather than just the main content field?

I have a CPT using custom fields, and rather than creating a function to output only X chars, appending an ellipse while taking into account trailing whitespace etc it would *seem* WP already has this functionality.

Comment: Can't you just use the PHP `trim()` and `substr()` functions? For example, this would output the first 100 characters - `substr(trim($string), 0, 100)`.  True, no ellipse, but you are in custom function territory if you want that.

Comment: "X chars, appending an ellipse while taking into account trailing whitespace"

Comment: Why would it *seem* that WP already has this functionality?  You may be thinking of `the_excerpt()`\`get_the_excerpt(), but these are designed to output post content, not a custom value.

Comment: Exactly. Hence why im asking if it can be hooked into with other content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the function you need is [`wp_trim_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt). With this function you can generate a excerpt from any text:

```
$text = "Some context";

$excerpt = wp_trim_excerpt( $text );
```

It is important to note that `wp_trim_excerpt` use the excerpt length set by WordPress, that is 55 words by default, and make use of [`excerpt_lenght` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length), so it will work with any plugin or theme that hook in this filter to define a custom excerpt length. If `$text` is greater than the excerpt length, `$text` is trimmed and ellips is appended. What to append can be modified using [`excerpt_more` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more).

You may also be interested in [`wp_trim_words`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words). This function uses also 55 words limit by default and it also append ellips by default. This function doesn't use `excerpt_lenght` filter nor `excerpt_more` filter. To modify the lenght and what to append you have to pass that options directly to the function:

```
$text = "Some context";
$words = 55;
$more = "&hellip;";

$excerpt = wp_trim_words( $text, $words, $more );
```